# $LU$ Factorization

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose the $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is nonsingular and that $A = LU$ is its $LU$ factorization. Give an algorithm that can compute, $e_i^TA^{-1}e_j$,i.e., the $(i,j)$ element of $A^{-1}$ in approximately $(n-j)^2 + (n-i)^2$ operations.

Attempted solution: We have \begin{align*}
A &= LU\\
e_i^{T}A^{-1}e_j &= e_i^{T}(LU)^{-1}e_j\\
&= (e_i^{T}U^{-1})(L^{-1}e_j)
\end{align*}
So we can construct an algorithm as so:

1. Solve the unit lower triangular system $Lv = e_j$
2. Solve the lower triangular system $U^T w = e_i$
3. Evaluate $w^T v$

Now what I am confused about is showing that we have $(n-j)^2 + (n- i)^2$ computations. Any comments or suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct. The goal of the exercise is to exploit the structure of the right hand side in order to reduce the number of arithmetic operations. There are a few points which I would like to make. It would be to your advantage to write 
\begin{equation}
e_i^T A^{-1} e_j = e_i^T (LU)^{-1} e_j = e_i^T U^{-1} L^{-1} e_j = (U^{-T} e_i)^T (L^{-1}e_j)
\end{equation} 
and then define $r_i$, $s_j$ as the solution of the linear system
\begin{align}
U^T r_i &= e_i \\
L s_j &= e_j
\end{align}
so that you could write
\begin{equation}
e_i^T A^{-1} e_j = r_i^T s_j.
\end{equation}
This would stress the critical point that you are not explicitly inverting matrices, but are solving linear system, i.e. computing the action of the inverse matrices. It is both more accurate and faster to proceed in this manner.

When counting the flops you could partition the matrices conformally with the given structure. For example, if you are faced with
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
L_{11} &  \\
L_{21} & L_{22}
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} f_1 \\ f_2 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
and have chosen the partitioning, such that $f_1 = 0$, then it follows that the computation of $x_1=0$ can be avoided and that it only remains to solve $L_{22} x_2 = f_2$.

EDIT: In particular if $f=e_j$, then we partition $f$ as $f=(x_1,x_2)^T$ were $f_1$ is the zero vector with $j-1$ components and $f_2$ is the first column vector of the identity matrix of dimension $n-(j-1)$. We partition $L$ and $x$ conformally. We have
\begin{equation}
L_{11} x_1 = f_1, \quad L_{21} x_1 + L_{22} x_2 = f_2
\end{equation}
Since $f_1 = 0$ we know that $x_1=0$ and it is wasteful to do arithmetic operations to find these zeros. Moreover, the second equation reduces to 
\begin{equation}
L_{22} x_2 = f_2
\end{equation}
The dimension of this unit lower triangular linear system is $n_j = n-(j-1) = n - j + 1$. In general, such linear systems can be solved using $n_j(n_j-1) = (n-j+1)(n-j)$ arithmetic operations. If we want to be fanatically about the flop count, then we can save $(n-j)$ subtractions, because the $x_2$ contains $n-j$ known zeros. This gets the flop count down to $(n-j)^2$.

Exploiting the structure of the right hand side is done in the truncated Spike algorithm for solving narrow banded linear system which are also diagonally dominant by rows. Here the right hand sides are almost entirely zero with the only nonzero elements concentrated at either the top or the bottom of the vector. Moreover, there are applications in quantum mechanics and photogrammetry which require the calculation of entries of the inverse matrix, so this is not an empty exercise.

Comment: Looking back at my question I don't really see how we have $(n-i)^2 + (n-j)^2$ computations

Comment: To me at step 1 in the algorithm described in my answer we have $n$ multiplications and $n-1$ additions??

Comment: @Wolfy: The cost of computing the LU decomposition and solving triangular linear systems is discussed here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1640730/order-of-lu-factorisation/1641606#1641606 It explains why the cost of solving a lower triangular linear system is $O(n^2)$ operations in the general case. In your case, savings are possible because the right hand side vector is very special. Most of entries are zeros and this leads to savings. In the extreme case all but the last entry is a zero. Such a lower triangular system can be solved using just a *single* operation, a division.

Comment: Right I know that it is $O(n^2)$ for solving lower triangular linear systems but I don't get the $(n-i)^2$ part

Comment: By the way this course is computational mathematics and the professor is Kyle Gallivan I noticed on your website that his name popped up so you may know him

Comment: @Wolfy I have added a paragraph to my answer with covers our discussion. Out of curiosity: which website are you referring to?

Comment: Your website on your profile. I saw that my professors name was on there do you know Kyle Gallivan?

Comment: I still don't understand completely so when we solve the unit lower triangular system $Lv = e_j$ we have $n$ multiplications and $n-1$ additions correct?

Comment: @Wolfy No. If you ignore the structure of the problem, then you do $n(n-1)$ operations. If you take the structure of the right hand side into account, then you can do the solve in $(n-j)^2$ operations. There is now way that you can eliminate the fact that the cost is quadratic in the system size. It could be that you are thinking about the cost for the entire linear system or just the cost per row?

Comment: I was thinking of just counting the number of operations from step 1, step 2, and then step 3 to show that we have a total of $(n-i)^2 + (n-j)^2$ operations.

Comment: @Wolfy. I probably meet Prof. Gallivan at a conference, but I can't say I know him. He was an editor on a book to which I contributed a chapter.

Comment: I need some help if you are still around?

Comment: Why would we choose the partitioning such that $f_1 = 0$?

Comment: To clearly identify the only arithmetic operations that we need to do. "Since $f_1=0$ we know that $x_1=0$ and it is wasteful to do arithmetic operations to find these zeros."

Comment: Ok, so we make $f_1 = 0$ because we know that the number of operations we need to figure out are for $f_2$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: ok, so then we just need to figure out how many arithmetic operations are in $$L_{22}x_2 = f_2$$ which you say has the dimension $n_j = n-(j-1) = n-j + 1$ I don't really see that