# Lu decomposition,inverse - number of multiplications

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods

A couple of questions:

- How many multiplications are needed for LU decomposition?
- How many multiplications are needed for finding the answer to $Ax = b$ by solving it like this $x=A^{-1}b$

The course I'm studying is low level and this is the hardest thing I'm struggling with right now is to understand that. Thanks!

Comment: Hi there I think it depends on the size of the matrix, ie the number of rows and columns. It will vary problem to problem. Can you elaborate if that isn’t helpful please? Thx!

Comment: Nope I'm looking for a more general approach iv'e seen something similar to this : To get UU, you have to eliminate n(n−1)/2n(n−1)/2 terms below the main diagonal. Each elimination requires computing the row multiplier, which involves division by the pivotal element.

Implementing this verbatim, one gets n(n−1)/2n(n−1)/2 divisions. However, as Algebraic Pavel notes, one can compute the reciprocal of the pivot first, and then the rest is multiplication. Hence, n−1n−1 divisions.

The subsequent computation of LL involves no divisions.

I didn't quiet understand that

Comment: Answer to closely related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1641606/30794499)