# Band matrix $A$ with bandwidth $m$. Count number of operations for LU decomposition.

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, computational-complexity

My definition of band matrix: $A_{ij} = 0$ for $|i-j|>m$.

I have to count the number of additions, multiplications and divisions for the LU decomposition without pivoting of a matrix $A$ with bandwidth $m$. And I have to count this for the solution $L \cdot Ux = b$.

I have already a solution, but I don't understand it.

Solution:

(1) in the $k$th step of the elimnationpart we need $m-1,...,1$ operations for the rows $k+1,...,k+m$.

(2) So this step need $\frac{1}{2}m(m-1)$ operations.

(3) The complete eliminationspart needs $\frac{1}{2}nm(m-1)$ operations.

(4) For $L$ and $U$ we need $m$ operation for every variable.

(5) So the complete resolutionpart needs $2nm$ operations.

I hope you can help me with (1) (2) and (4). I really tried to understand this solution, but I failed. So I need a detailed explanation.

Comment: There is more than one way to define the bandwidth, what is your definition? Have you written an implementation of the LU decomposition for a banded matrix?

Comment: Thanks for noticing! I have edited my definition of bandwidth. No unfortunately I haven't.

Comment: When seeking to understand an algorithm there is *no* substitute for implementing it. The code will be structured exactly as a the factorization of a dense matrix, but the inner loops will never be longer than $m$. When you have a working code, you can augment it to count all the operations it completes. You will then be able to verify any hypothesis that you might care to make. In the end, you will be able to count the operations correctly. An example of this technique is given in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1641606/307944)